# Dark mode take more time to load the picture than light mode

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, ios-darkmode

I'm making my app support the dark mode, but I encountered a problem. When the app is in the dark mode, it will take much more time to load the picture than light mode. I hope to get help, thank you very much.

Dark mode time profiler [image: Dark mode time profiler]Light mode time profiler [image: Light mode time profiler]Dark mode stack trace [image: Dark mode detail stack trace]Light mode stack trace[image]

Comment: Are you sure the images have the same size, compression, etc?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel Yes, same placement, same image, just the difference between dark mode and light mode.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that your image does not have different variants based on system Appearances?

[image: Xcode showing variants of an image based on light/dark mode]

Comment: These images are not set to dark appearances, they are all None appearances, but it takes different time to load in dark mode.